# LeaseLostException in single instance of EventProcessorHost for IOT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, event-processor-host

I have created a simple event processor host which reads events from Azure IOT hub configured with the default options for lease management. 
But at regular intervals, I get following exception even though I am running single instance of the EventProcessorHost:
**ReceiverDisconnectedException: New receiver with higher epoch is created hence current receiver with epoch is getting disconnected. Reason: LeaseLost**

The client re-acquires the lease and process messages further.

Here is the initialization of the EventProcessorHost

```
EventProcessorHost eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(hostName, eventHubName, EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName,
            eventHubConnectionString, storageAccountConnectionString);
var options = new EventProcessorOptions();
options.ExceptionReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Exception);
};

eventProcessorHost.PartitionManagerOptions = PartitionManagerOptions.DefaultOptions;
eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(options).Wait();
```

Is this behaviour normal or I need to do something to avoid it for a single instance?

Below is my EventProcessor:

```
public class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    Stopwatch checkpointStopWatch;

    public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason);
        await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SimpleEventProcessor initialized.  Partition: '{0}', Offset: '{1}'", context.Lease.PartitionId, context.Lease.Offset);
        this.checkpointStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        this.checkpointStopWatch.Start();
        this.rawDataService = new RawDataService();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
    {
        foreach (EventData eventData in messages)
        {
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received.  Partition: '{0}', Data: '{1}'", context.Lease.PartitionId, data));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I tested above code with running single instance of the EventProcessorHost, there is no exception thrown,but I reproduce the issue by running two app.Please check wheather other reciever has been created in other app host.And could you share more code to let me know more.

Comment: I have updated the question to include my Event Processor code. Also, I am getting this error at no fixed time. It may come in the first 30 seconds and may not until 5 minutes. Also, I am running this locally and no other receiver instance is running.

Comment: Please try to create a new consumer group for the event hub endpoint,and then modify the EventProcessorHost's consumeGroupName parameter as you created when initialized.If it is ok, there must be some other connection has been established.

Comment: I will try this and update the thread.